# Ejecutar un proceso en segundo plano PHP

Tags: php, windows, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Necesito `ejecutar` una `función` en `segundo plano` que tarda mucho tiempo desde "entre 30m a 1 hora, esto puede variar algunas ocaciónes tarda hasta 5m" esto en  `php` pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, leí algo sobre `cocur/background-process` pero no  me funciono no me muerta nada  alguien que me pueda ayudar.

el sistema esta montado en `windows`

Comment: Tienes cpanel? Podrias utilizar una tarea cron, cuentanos un poco mas para que necesitas esto :)

Comment: Hola @Patrick veras tengo una serie de funciones (tareas) que tardan al rededor de 5 minutos mas  dependiendo cual sea, una de ellas es para cerrar todo un proceso, lo cual manda llamar un procedimiento y en lo que termina de realizar la operación aparece un icono de loader, entonce el usuario no puede hacer mas en el sistema entonces quiero hacer eso proceso en segundo plano para que el usurario pueda seguir usando el sistema, no se si me explique.

Comment: Ah ya, la verdad no entiendo mucho sobre windows y tareas... Pero por logica pienso que podrias poner como ultima tarea eliminar el proceso, tal vez?

Comment: si al final que termine se elimina y se mostraría algo que indique que ya termino,  la cosa es que no se como hacer que inicie esa tarea  después de que el usuario lo indique intente hacerlo con  background-process que esta en https://github.com/cocur/background-process pero no me muestra nada

Comment: Voto el cierre de esta pregunta por estar basada en opiniones. **El patrón de diseño más adecuado para resolver este problema es el de publicar/suscribir mensajes en una cola**. Tu aplicación produce un mensaje (que se puede guardar en una base de datos o en un servidor especializado para gestionar colas de mensajes) indicando el trabajo que se debe realizar y un programa suscrito a dicha cola obtiene el trabajo y lo procesa de manera completamente independiente, marcando el trabajo como finalizado al completar la tarea o enviando otro mensaje indicando eso mismo.

Comment: Se puede implementar ese proceso que consume los mensajes de la cola de multitud de maneras. Un proceso programado en el programador de tareas de Windows, un servicio de Windows que ejecuta en un bucle infinito la lectura del siguiente mensaje, una tarea que se ejecuta en primer plano en un símbolo del sistema de Windows (y que si se cierra deja de atender trabajo), etc. Deberías centrarte en comprender el patrón de diseño y luego estudiar las diferentes maneras de implementarlo y, por último, implementarlo y consultarnos cualquier duda que encuentre en el proceso.